# (TextView)findbyid crashes application Android.

Tags: android, textview, logcat

When i try to create a textview and link it to a XML component in my application my app seems to crash. the code i am using is:

```
public class WorkoutAdvice extends Activity {
TextView adviceshow;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] advice = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.races_array);
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int ad = rand.nextInt(5);
    String gen = advice[ad];
    adviceshow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.advice);
    adviceshow.setText(gen);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.advice);       

}
}
```

and the logcat for when my application closes is

> 05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.b00348312.workout/com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutAdvice}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutAdvice.onCreate(WorkoutAdvice.java:22)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   05-26 01:43:23.018: E/AndroidRuntime(363):  ... 11 more

the application works without the statements dealing with the findbyID lines which work in other parts of the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you actually set your activity content by calling `setContentView`, there are no views to be found. Once you have called `setContentView`, then you may try to find your `TextView`. Note that before this call, the `Activity` has no knowledge at all of which(s) XML layouts will it be binded to (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
setContentView(R.layout.advice);
```

before of

```
adviceshow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.advice);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should setContentView before you use findViewById.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class WorkoutAdvice extends Activity {
TextView adviceshow;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.advice);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 adviceshow = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.advice);
    String[] advice = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.races_array);
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int ad = rand.nextInt(5);
    String gen = advice[ad];

    adviceshow.setText(gen);
   }}
```

It should be like this way